# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.acubeitsolution.Client_Review_getter_setter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

## Below is the Complete code :

### Please tell me the solution

I am getting this error while retrieving data from Firebase realtime database
Activity is crashing after a while automatically:

[image]

Getting error  at this line:-

```
Client_Review_getter_setter CRArr=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Client_Review_getter_setter.class);
```

```
`This is my Fragment code :-`


   

 package com.example.acubeitsolution;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Client_Review_getter_setter> list;
    Client_Review_AdapterClass adapter;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_fragment,container,false);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.chat_fragment_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        list=new ArrayList<Client_Review_getter_setter>();
        if(checkConnection() == true) {
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ClientReview");
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Client_Review_getter_setter CRArr=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Client_Review_getter_setter.class);
                        list.add(CRArr);
                    }
                    adapter = new Client_Review_AdapterClass(getActivity(),list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    databaseError.getDetails();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No internet connection\n\nTrun on wifi / mobile data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        return  view;

    }
    public boolean checkConnection()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo active_Network=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(null != active_Network)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

`This is my Getter Setter class :-`

````
 package com.example.acubeitsolution;

public class Client_Review_getter_setter {
    private String CompanyName;
    private String CompanyReview;
    private String CompanyLogo;

    public Client_Review_getter_setter(String companyName, String companyReview, String companyLogo) {
        CompanyName = companyName;
        CompanyReview = companyReview;
        CompanyLogo = companyLogo;
    }

    public Client_Review_getter_setter() {
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return CompanyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        CompanyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCompanyReview() {
        return CompanyReview;
    }

    public void setCompanyReview(String companyReview) {
        CompanyReview = companyReview;
    }

    public String getCompanyLogo() {
        return CompanyLogo;
    }

    public void setCompanyLogo(String companyLogo) {
        CompanyLogo = companyLogo;
    }
}

`This is my Adapter class :-`

   



  package com.example.acubeitsolution;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client_Review_AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Client_Review_AdapterClass.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Client_Review_getter_setter> ClientReviewArr;

    public Client_Review_AdapterClass(Context c, ArrayList<Client_Review_getter_setter> CRArr) {
        context=c;
        ClientReviewArr=CRArr;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new  MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.client_review_cardview,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.CompanyName.setText(ClientReviewArr.get(position).getCompanyName());
        holder.CompanyReview.setText(ClientReviewArr.get(position).getCompanyReview());
        Picasso.get().load(ClientReviewArr.get(position).getCompanyLogo()).into(holder.CompanyLogo);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ClientReviewArr.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView CompanyName, CompanyReview;
        ImageView CompanyLogo;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            CompanyName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_review_cardview_company_name);
            CompanyReview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_review_cardview_company_review_description);
            CompanyLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_review_cardview_companylogo_imageview);


        }
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Client_Review_getter_setter CRArr=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Client_Review_getter_setter.class);
                        list.add(CRArr);
                    }
                    adapter = new Client_Review_AdapterClass(getActivity(),list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
```

into this:

```
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Client_Review_getter_setter CRArr=dataSnapshot.getValue(Client_Review_getter_setter.class);
                        list.add(CRArr);
                    adapter = new Client_Review_AdapterClass(getActivity(),list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
```

Remove the for loop, since when you are iterating you are retrieving the valus of type String and not of the modal class that you created.

Comment: i wanted to retrieve all the children from that node , so removing loop will retrieve all the children? whenever i add new children in database

Comment: @GholapAkshay Since the answer helped you please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it so others know that it is helpful, thank you!